# activity orientation change bug

Tags: java, android, android-layout, screen-orientation, device-orientation

I'm experiencing a weird bug that I haven't seen in an Android application before. When navigating from an activity locked in portrait mode to an activity locked in landscape mode and back, the activity that's supposed to be in portrait appears in portrait mode, goes to landscape and then back to portrait.

This happens while the device is flat on the table with no actual orientation changes.  I'm using two separate activities, and that's the only code that I have in the project.

[Here](https://youtu.be/I0vnhfKt2M8) is a video of the bug, and [here's a link](https://github.com/DaneMackier/AndroidOrientationBug) to the exact project that reproduces this bug. It happens on more than one device so it's not isolated to my device.

**Questions:**

- Do you know what could be causing this?
- Is there anything that you can recommend for fixing this?

**Things I've tried:**

- Setting the orientation programatically
- Googling and not finding anything

**Update 1**

**More things I've tried:**

- Setting the portrait activity to "nosensor" and the landscape one to "landscape"
- Setting the portrait activity to "nosensor" and programatically setting the landscape activity in onCreate

**Update 2**

I've been working with the project linked above and just did some overrides to log out everything that's happening. I found that when the onConfigurationChanged is called it does the little shimmy between the landscape and the portrait orientations. The output for a back navigation that doesn't do the shimmy is:

```
D/class com.mdk_studio.orientationbugtests.MainActivity: onStateNotSaved
D/class com.mdk_studio.orientationbugtests.MainActivity: onRestart
D/class com.mdk_studio.orientationbugtests.MainActivity: onWindowFocusChanged
```

The output for the shimmy bug is:

```
D/class com.mdk_studio.orientationbugtests.MainActivity: onStateNotSaved
D/class com.mdk_studio.orientationbugtests.MainActivity: onRestart
D/class com.mdk_studio.orientationbugtests.MainActivity: onWindowFocusChanged
D/class com.mdk_studio.orientationbugtests.MainActivity: onConfigurationChanged
D/class com.mdk_studio.orientationbugtests.MainActivity: onConfigurationChanged
```

I guess the question now becomes, how do I make sure the orientation change does not get called?

Comment: I would suggest to not lock orientation at all.

Comment: Try this : android:screenOrientation="nosensor"   alternative for android:screenOrientation="portrait "

Comment: @egoldx so no lock and just set orientation programatically? And how would you make sure and activity cannot go into portrait when landscape, and landscape when portrait?

Comment: @VirajMohite I changed the android:screenOrientation to "nosensor" for both activities and then set the LandscapeActivity to landscape using setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);. It still does the same thing.

Comment: No, don't use for both activities use only for activity which you want to keep in portrait mode.

Comment: @VirajMohite Added "nosensor" to MainActivity and "landscape" to my LandscapeActivity and it's still happening. It didn't happen the first three navigations, after that it happens everytime. 

You can download the project and run it and see if your ideas will work.

Comment: Strange I just tried on 2 different devices and there's no problem...
Can you test on some other device?

Comment: @makvasic yes I've tried on s8, nokia 3, nokia 2, Nexus 5x. They all do it. On some devices it only happens after 6-10 tries. When it happens once, then it happens every time after that. But I just figured out how to get it to work. Posting an answer now.

Comment: This solution worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381441/7826494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing out all the different combinations of manifest level orientation setting and programmatic orientation setting. I have figured out that for the orientation to not be wrong in the onConfigurationChanged function you have to set the orientation before the navigation is actually started.

The combination that worked for me and took the behaviour away completely was to set the activity in the manifest that I want in portrait to "nosensor". Then set the activity that I want in landscape to landscape using

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

and set the orientation back to portrait in the onBackPressed **before** the navigation occures. That part is important, once the navigation has been triggered and then you set the orientation,  in some cases when the newConfiguration comes through in the onConfigurationChanged call it has the wrong orientation, and then it somehow issues another call to it to correct it after it's been updated on the first call.

*tl;dr*
Set the orientation for the activity you want in portrait to "nosensor". Programatically set the orientation to landscape in onCreate. Set the orientation back to portrait in onBackPressed, **before the super call**.